# What is the counterpart for cdf in measure theory?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am interested in the correspondence between probability and measure theory. Currently, I know that a random variable is a measurable function, a probability function is a measure, etc.,

But, I am confused about whether the cumulative distribution function is also a measure like a probability function, or does it have any more accurate counterpart in measure theory?

Comment: Given $f(x)$, the equivalent to cdf is $\int\limits_{-\infty}^x f(u)du$.

Comment: The cdf is a measurable probability, over the interval $(-\infty,x]$

Comment: Relevant to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764604/probability-measure-as-a-synonym-of-cumulative-distribution-function-cdf/4764629?noredirect=1#comment10117923_4764629

Answer (score 2):

CDFs are in one to one correspondence with probability measures in the sense that if you have a right continuous increasing function $F : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ with $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x) = 1$, then $F$ is the cdf of a unique probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. One method of proof is to let $U$ be uniform on $(0, 1)$, and let $X = F^{-1}(U)$, where $F^{-1} : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$F^{-1}(u) = \inf\{x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x) = u\}.$$
Then $X$ has CDF $F$.