# "Probability measure" as a synonym of "Cumulative Distribution Function" (CDF)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If

1. a $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets of a given set $\Omega$, and
2. a "probability measure" is a function that assigns to each element of a given $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. to each subset of $\Omega$) a value between 0 and 1,

Can I use the term "probability measure" as synonym of "cumulative distribution function" (CDF)?

If yes, would it be correct to write, in a paper, something like this: "We call the two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, as cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$, respectively?"

Or, am I saying a huge bull***t ?

Comment: Why do you think we must have $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let's say that we consider the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$... better? Probably I should have mentioned it...

Comment: Why not write "Probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ have corresponding cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$"?

Comment: Yes, that sounds really good!

Comment: @DilipSarwate Do you think the following statement could be correct as well? "We consider the two cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$, **associated with** the probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the CDF is not a measure, it is instead a monotone function.

Now, there is a 1-1 correspondence between probability measures on $\mathbb R$ and CDF's.  That is, if $F$ is a CDF, then you can define a unique probability measure $\nu_F$ on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $\nu_F((-\infty,x))=F(x)$ for each $x$, and similarly, given the probability measure on $\mathbb R$ you define $F$.

However, if $X$ is a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mu)$, with CDF $F$, then the aforementioned measure $\nu_F$ is NOT equal to $\mu$.  It is instead the so-called "pushforward" of $\mu$ by the map $X$ (recall that random variables are just maps from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ -- I am for simplicity only discussing real valued random variables here).

More precisely, $\nu_F(A)=\mu(X^{-1}(A))$ for every measurable $A\subseteq \mathbb R$.

So, if one were writing a paper, one might say that $F$ is the CDF associated with $X$, but that and $\mu$ are two totally different animals and should not be identified.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks a lot! I have a couple of doubts.. **The first doubt.** If (i) the CDF is defined as $F_{X}(x)=P(X<x)$, that should represent the area under the "density curve" over the interval $(\infty,x]$, and if (ii) the probability measure $\nu_{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\nu_{F}(-\infty,x)=F_{X}(x)$, then, I would say that: $\nu_{F}(-\infty,x)=P(X<x)$, which, to my understanding, would lead both the probability measure $\nu_{F}$ and the CDF $F_{X}(x)$ to return the same value, $\forall x$... Right or wrong?

Comment: "$\nu_{F}((-\infty,x))=P(X<x)$" is correct (I added extra parentheses which technically are required), however $\nu_F$ is a measure, and does not does not take real numbers as inputs, it takes sets as inputs.  So it makes no sense to say it returns the same value for all $x$.  $\nu_F(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: About the first doubt, thanks for the clarification!!!! ...I feel that a "probability measure" lies in a upper level of abstraction, if/when we try to compare or put into a relationship with more down-to-earth functions as the CDF....  this is just my feeling :-)

Comment: **Second doubt (part 1)** I am thinking about some topics on Optimal Transport, like the Monge-Kantorovich minimization problem (pls see, Villani, C., Optimal transport: old and new(2009))... where one has to find the "joint probability measure" $\pi$
(whose marginals are the above mentioned probability measure $\mu$
 and $\nu$), which minimises a "total transportation cost" associated to $\pi$.

Comment: **Second doubt (part 2)** When people try to numerically solve that problem, they usually employ (to the best of my understanding) empirical CDFs (coming from empirical frequency distributions?) as input, in place of the abstract "probability measures"..... Then, at least in principle, it would not be super wrong to think about CDFs as proxies for "probability measures"... right or wrong?

Comment: @limone I would really say that's wrong.  I can't speak to what they are doing numerically, I'm certain they do use CDF's, that doesn't mean they are using them "in place of probability measures".  I don't know what you mean by "Proxy", I would certainly not describe it as a proxy - its a different animal entirely.  The CDF has an association with the pushforward measure for your random variable but its not something you would substitute in place of that measure.

Comment: Ah ok, clear !! Many thanks for clarifying all the doubts! :-)

Comment: Relevant to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444848/what-is-the-counterpart-for-cdf-in-measure-theory

Comment: This is also relevant to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730499/help-understanding-measure-theory-definitions-of-expectations-and-densities?rq=1

Comment: **Equivalence between a CDF and a Borel Probability Measure on $\mathbb{R}$** here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wV3JuVI2tLM

Comment: **A probability measure is more like a cumulative distribution function** (from @usul)  here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384923/what-exactly-is-a-probability-measure-in-simple-words

Comment: This is relevant as well to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976739/on-clarifying-the-relationship-between-distribution-functions-in-measure-theory

Answer (score 1):

i think a CDF is a probability measure but a probability measure does not have to be a CDF because a propability measure does not have to be non-decreasing. It just needs to be positive for all inputs. So i should not use them as synonyms.

Comment: Yes, true, ```a propability measure does not have to be non-decreasing```,  while a CDF is non decreasing and right continuous.... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't exactly correct.  A probability measure is also nondecreasing, in its own way, that is if $A\subseteq B$ then $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$, which is why there is a natural correspondence between prob measures and CDFs in $\mathbb R$.  The underlying issue is not an issue with monotonicity, its a matter of the probability measure need not live in $\mathbb R$, and even if it does it isn't the same as the measure associated with a CDF for a random variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)